# Redirect K2 article url after alias change

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, joomla-3.5, seo, redirect

I need to change the alias of a K2 article from `id-alias1` to `id-alias2`.
The issue is that search engines have already indexed the url with `id-alias1` so I need to use a 301 redirect from `id-alias1`to `id-alias2` to avoid both urls to be indexed and considered as duplicate content.

I tried using the native joomla redirect component but it has no effect on these urls.

Is there a way to make 301 redirect between these 2 urls with the redirect component or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redirect Manager only works if the URL of the first article returns a 404 error. If it doesn't, then the redirect will not take place.

I suggest you do this redirect in the `.htaccess` file by adding the following (after `RewriteManager On`):

```
REDIRECT 301 /sub-1/id-alias1 http://www.yourwebsite.com/sub-1/id-alias2
```

If the first URL is `http://www.yourwebsite.com/sub-1/id-alias1` and the second URL is `http://www.yourwebsite.com/sub-1/id-alias2`

Redirects in the .htaccess file are the most efficient and you don't have to install any extension for them to work.

Comment: Thx, it works but I didn't understand the code `RewriteManager On` you mention. Shouldn't it be after `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: Yes  - ideally it should be after `RewriteEngine On`.